# LINQ for untyped IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am getting the `e` object via Reflection and then, if it is an `IEnumerable`, dump it to string:

```
public static string EnumerableToString(this IEnumerable e, string separator)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (object item in e)
        list.Add($"\"{item}\"");
    return "[" + string.Join(separator, list) + "]";
}
```

I wonder whether there is a more compact way to do this with LINQ. The `Select` method of LINQ is only applicable to `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: You can do `e.OfType<object>().Select(x => $"\"{x}\"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OfType` method:

```
public static string EnumerableToString(this IEnumerable e, string separator)
{
    return $"[{string.Join(separator, e.OfType<object>().Select(x => $"\"{x}\""))}]";
}
```